# Mysql insert with with dynamic values from nested value

Tags: node.js

Normally i have this sql command to query in node,

```
 var sql = "INSERT INTO customers (name, address) VALUES ('Company Inc', 'Highway 37')";
  con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("1 record inserted");
  });
```

Now my case is like this

```
 var sql = "INSERT INTO customers (id, address) VALUES (
             SELECT id from companies where name='Company Inc', 
             'Highway 37')";
```

Can this still work in node ?

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: Not tried yet, i cannot think clearly about the syntax yet